# How to remove unwanted UIMenuItems from UITextfields UIMenuController?

Tags: ios, uimenucontroller

In my application I am showing a `UIMenuController` with menus `share`, `delete`, etc for a `UITableViewCell` long press gesture.

It works perfectly, but after showing the menu, the default `UIMenuController` of `UITextfield` also has `copy`, `paste`, `select` menu items.

How do I remove these 'standard' menu items?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the method

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action
              withSender:(id)sender
```

and return YES for actions you want and NO for actions you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But still the old menus are coming.

Comment: What are the menus you want get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

Override the method of UITextfield as below

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But still the old menus are coming